SQL Server 2019 Hard Dependency on ODBC Drivers
When installing SQL Server 2019, ODBC drivers are also installed at the same time that MSSQL seems to have a hard dependency on. Can MSSQL be reconfigured to use newer versions of ODBC drivers and the older versions removed? The older versions of ODBC drivers are being flagged by our third party vulnerability management scanner and there doesn't appear to be a way to cleanly remediate these findings.
Details as of this writing:

The server I am working with is running SQL Server 2019 developer edition
It is running on a Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition VM
This SQL server is at version 15.0.4405.4 (CU29)
Prior to installing CU29, this server was at CU27
The ODBC version installed is 17.10.6.1
All components are x64, not x86

Troubleshooting/Analysis:

Updating from CU27 to CU29 did not update the version of the ODBC driver
I can manually install a newer version of the ODBC driver (18.4.1.1) and it will coexist peacefully with 17.10.6.1 but will not clear the vulnerability
If I remove 17.10.6.1 to clear the vulnerability, the SQL Server Agent will fail to start (Event Viewer: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion)
Reinstalling ODBC 17.10.6.1 fixes the problem and allows the agent to start - but the vulnerability reappears
Repairing SQL Server following an install of the v18.x driver just reinstalls the ODBC driver to an earlier major version (17.x.x.x) which is just as non-compliant and still triggers findings in our vulnerability scans
There don't appear to be newer versions of ODBC 17 yet, as MS doesn't seem to be doing parallel development and releasing newer versions of both 17.x and 18.x. They seem to nudge us to v18, which doesn't play nicely with the SQL 2019 Agent.

Takeaways:

It seems that MSSQL 2019 has a hard dependency on version 17 of the ODBC driver for SQL 2019
CU's don't appear to update these drivers - yet (if at all)
There does not appear to be a way to reconfigure/tweak MSSQL 2019 to use a newer major version (e.g. 18.x) of the ODBC driver through SSMS/UI
I've not investigated Windows system registry edits yet
Regardless of what components I install at instance build time, these drivers get installed, so it doesn't appear that minimizing my surface area helps (I compared this instance to another 2019 instance with a minimal install performed - they both had the same ODBC drivers.)

Questions:

Has anyone here run into the same problem(s) and are there steps I can take to get MSSQL to see/use newer ODBC drivers?
Will ODBC driver updates get pushed with CUs, or do I need to be updating them manually via official MS downloads?

Any advice/guidance appreciated. Thanks.

Which vulnerability are we talking about?

You are correct, depending on the version of SQL Server there are various components which may require different version of drivers. I wrote about this (in the general sense of AG/FCI, but it applies to Agent and internal engine items as well) and you can see that SQL 2019 does require ODBC 17.
To your question, updates to the ODBC driver for major version (as in they overwrite the earlier binaries of the same major version) can be updated, typically ODBC drivers come in their own updates.
Updates between major versions, for example in the OP from 17 to 18, does not allow for the newer major version to be used. In the most simplest case it is because the application (for example, Agent) was compiled with the 17 driver hard coded.
If there is truly a vulnerability in the driver, and the version of SQL Server is still supported, then there should be an update to the driver to address that issue. Note that only vulnerabilities classified as critical are addressed for out of mainstream support software.
